# Spring Cloud : Using routing type filter in Zuul

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I have 2 micro-services (Service A and Service B) built using Spring Boot,  which gets routed through a Zuul Proxy also built as a Spring Boot app and I have checked that the Zuul proxy works just fine. However, what I am trying to do is to write a custom routing type ZuulFilter which should first route to Service A when a request comes in for Service B. Here is what I need assistance for:

1. I would like to know an example of how a routing filter looks like as I do not see anything after searching the internet. What I get are some examples of pre-filter and [Netflix's documentation](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/wiki/How-it-Works) doesn't help much as well on that aspect.
2. Whether writing a custom route filter would mess up the original routing behavior of Zuul

Comment: So...Zuul calls Service A which then proxies Service B, or that Zuul calls Service A first, and once that request has completed, Zuul calls to Service B?

Comment: So, the request comes in for Service B which Zuul is proxying, but using a ZuulFilter, Service A is invoked and based on its response Service B should be proxied by Zuul.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would construct a [Feign client](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#spring-cloud-feign) in the Zuul filter and make the call to service A using it. Feign will populate a ribbon load balancer to make the call in just the same way that Zuul does when proxying.

Comment: Just to understand further, so the Feign Client will call the Zuul provided endpoint for Service A as there could be multiple instances of Service A, correct? If yes, then won't it be an overhead as compared to allow some configuration within Zuul to route it automatically within itself?

Comment: The feign client populates its ribbon load balancer from the same discovery client (sourced from Eureka) that Zuul uses so yes, they are effectively using the same source and the same underlying method of load balancing calls.

Comment: Could you please provide some example in order to help me understand how the routing would work?

Comment: I got it working by building a Feign client which itself uses service discovery to find out instances of Service A which i intended to call from a Zuul filter

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this is what I came up with.

```
public class ServicesLegacyRouteFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    private ServiceB serviceB;

    public ServiceLegacyRouteFilter(ServiceB serviceB) {
        this.serviceB = serviceB;
    }

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return ROUTE_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 10;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {

        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();

        if ("serviceA".equals(ctx.get("serviceId"))) {

            //call Service B here and use return type to set
            //the final destination service
            String destination = serviceB.routeWhere();
            ctx.set("serviceId", destination);

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {

        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();

        // Or call ServiceB here to make your determination on
        // the final destination.

        String destination = serviceB.routeWhere();
        ctx.set("serviceId", destination);


        return null;
    }
}
```

My actual production use case was more complicated on the routing of course, but this is the basics of how I was able to change routes based on what was coming in and how to take advantage of Zuul to get it out to the correct service.

Comment: I don't think this solution is relevant to my question. My problem was more based on service B acting as a decision maker on whether to call service A or not. Correct me, if I understood your solution incorrectly.

Comment: The routing filter could be used to call Service B either in the shouldFilter method or in the run method to determine the actual destination that is set. I will try to edit my response to make it more clear.

Comment: how is `ServiceB` class type even defined and how is it passed/injected in the constructor?  wouldn't this be better as an `@EnableConfigurationProperties(...)` class at the very least?